# Mercurial no color in commands after doing su

Tags: bash, su, mercurial

First noticed in 12.04 still persists in 14.04
This happens when to change to a system user (`www-data`, `postgres`, etc) and not for a user which has a desktop profile setup.

What I have tried:

- Copy `.profile` and `.bashrc` from a user to the `www-data` user which shows colors in the `ls` command but still no color in mercurial

Reproducing the problem (colors show for the first `hg stat` command but not the second):

```
sudo su -
hg stat
su - www-data
hg stat
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple configuration issue. You successfully got colored `ls` output after copying suitable `.bashrc` and `.profile` files to the other user's (e.g., `www-data`) home directory. Obtaining colored output in mercurial should presumably be as simple as additionally copying a suitable `.hgrc` file.

Also see [the mercurial man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html).

Comment: Actually its not that simple because there is no .hgrc file in any users profile. The color is coming by default in the root user and its not in the /etc/mercurial location either